# Implicit Template Instantiation compile time difference

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, compile-time

I have some pre written code that uses a hash table template described in ht.cc and ht.h. At the bottom of the description of ht.h it says:

```
#include "ht.cc"
```

I know this is to induce implicit template instantiation but in the comment section of the code it just says "icky but it works".
I don't understand the possible negative side affect the previous coder who wrote the template intended to hint at and if i could get any clarification that would be wonderful.
I was also wondering how my code (random othe .c files) would vary if at all during compile time on a g++ linux machine  if I were to include the stl unordered map compared to using the template.

Comment: "Implicit instantiation" only happens when something else makes use of a template - there's no way to cause it to happen without other additional code, and it wouldn't be very useful to do so anyway.  Explicit instantiation is something you can do from code. But often this pattern is just a way of separating template declarations and implementations into separate files, even though template definitions usually must be included.  So what is an example of the code inside ht.cc?

Comment: Ah okay after looking through the .cc file some more I think you are 100 percent correct, i think this is only there to separate the declaration from all of the implementation. I thought "icky" next to the include would mean a possible pressing problem i guess, my bad but thank you!